# Upload file through django restful api

Tags: python, django, curl, django-rest-framework, restful-architecture

I've read all the stackoverflow questions and answers and every tutorial that I an find but I still cannot get this to work--I might be dumb.  I'm trying to upload files to django via restful api through curl.  My curl command is as follows

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -u alex:password123 -F "docfile=@/Users/Alex/test.txt" http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/`

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class File(models.Model):

     title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
     docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='file/')
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.parsers import FormParser, MultiPartParser
from models import File
from serializers import FileSerializer

class UploadFile(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     queryset = File.objects.all()
     serializer_class = FileSerializer
     parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)


     def preform_create(self, serializer):
          file_obj = self.request.FILES['docfile'] 
          serializer.save(file_obj)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import File

class FileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

     class Meta:
         model = File
         fields = ('docfile','name')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from quickstart import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'files', views.UploadFile)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

My media root is `MEDIA_ROOT = ''`  I've read through a ton of documentation but I am really stuck on how all of this fits together/what I'm missing.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages of the REST API is that it comes with tons of classes to reduce the code you have to write for common operations, but if you are new to the API and you will upload files via `curl` maybe you should start with something simpler:

```
class UploadFile(views.APIView):
    parser_classes = (parsers.FormParser, parsers.MultiPartParser)

    def post(self, request):
        if len(request.FILES) > 0:
            request_file = request.FILES[0]
            file = File(docfile=request_file, title='something')
            file.save()
        else:
           # do something
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^files/$', views.UploadFile.as_view(), name='files'),
```

Once you master the different View's that the API offers you can try the `viewsets.ViewSet`. I personally prefer to extend my views from `views.APIView` and have more control on the code.